# Web services and web server in the same Maven project

Tags: java, web-services, maven

I am using Jetty into a Maven project to deploy a little web server. I want to deploy in the same project REST/SOAP services (I am following [This Tutorial](https://github.com/bibounde/embedded-guice-rest-soap-example)). If I compile with Maven only REST/SOAP works and if I compile with Jetty only webpages works.

Two questions:
1. How can I do to make both parts working?
2. SOAP currently is under CXF. How easy is migrate to AXIS2M?

Comment: Can you please add some code snippets to illustrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that, if you are using the same code in tutorial link pasted, then Main.java is not registering the CXFServlet. Now you will need to have two configurations on two separate port numbers, i.e one for the web application , the other for the SOAP Services. This will fix the problem.

So the Main class will need to be modified to have code similar to the previous and the new block as follows:

```
    Server server = new Server( 9090 );


    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet

    final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( new CXFServlet() );

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();  

    context.setContextPath( "/" );
    context.addServlet( servletHolder, "/rest/*" ); 
    context.addEventListener( new ContextLoaderListener() );
    context.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
    context.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getName() );    

    server.setHandler( context );

    server.start();

    server.join();
```

Source : http://aredko.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/embedded-jetty-and-apache-cxf-secure.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Ashok. Some libraries that you provide me in the code are from Spring. We want to avoid the use of Spring because is too heavy for our development. Could we use these libraries without using Spring? How could I use two ports? Thanks.